# Openjpa slice with spring issue

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, openjpa

I have been trying to configure openjpa-slice with spring boot. The configuration is shared as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class DatasourceConfiguration extends JpaBaseConfiguration{

@Bean(name = "slice1")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    DataSource dataSource = dataSourceLookup.getDataSource("java:/MysqlXADS");
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean(name = "slice2")
public DataSource dataSource2() {
    JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    DataSource dataSource = dataSourceLookup.getDataSource("java:/MysqlXADS2");
    return dataSource;
}

@Override
protected Map<String, Object> getVendorProperties() {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    return map;
}

public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    properties.put("openjpa.BrokerFactory", "slice");
    properties.put("openjpa.slice.Names", "One, Two");
    properties.put("openjpa.slice.Master", "Two");
    properties.put("openjpa.slice.Lenient", "false");
    properties.put("openjpa.slice.ConnectionDriverName", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    properties.put("openjpa.slice.One.ConnectionFactoryName", "java:/MysqlXADS");
    properties.put("openjpa.slice.Two.ConnectionFactoryName", "java:/MysqlXADS2");
    properties.put("openjpa.slice.DistributionPolicy", "com.services.sample.configuration.UserDistributionPolicy");
    properties.put("openjpa.slice.TransactionPolicy" , "xa");
    properties.put("openjpa.TransactionMode" , "managed");
    properties.put("openjpa.ConnectionFactoryMode", "managed");
    properties.put("openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary", "mysql");
    properties.put("openjpa.Log","DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE");

    return builder
            .dataSource(dataSource()).jta(true)
            .properties(properties)
            .packages("com.services.sample.domain.entity")
            .persistenceUnit("sample")
            .build();
}

@Override
protected AbstractJpaVendorAdapter createJpaVendorAdapter() {
    OpenJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new OpenJpaVendorAdapter();
    jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
    return jpaVendorAdapter;
}

public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory")EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory){
    JtaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JtaTransactionManager();
    return transactionManager;
}
```

}

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="sample" transaction-type="JTA" >
    <description>generated-persistence-unit</description>
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <class> ... </class>

</persistence-unit>
```

I have configured this with wildfly server 10. Both the xa-datasources point to different databases. However, when the application boots and I execute a query it just fetches the data from the datasource passed into the builder twice. Seems I have something wrong with the slice configuration. Not sure whats the problem in this case.

Comment: Where did you find documentation on how to implement JpaBaseConfiguration? Did you get it to work?